# How to map Emacs Evil keys to Dired Plus

Tags: emacs, dired

I want to bind my `h` and `l` keys to `diredp-up-directory-reuse-dir-buffer` and `diredp-find-file-reuse-dir-buffer` respectively. I have the following code in my `.emacs` file:

```
(require 'dired+)
(toggle-diredp-find-file-reuse-dir 1)
(eval-after-load 'dired
  '(evil-define-key 'normal dired-mode-map
     (kbd "h") 'diredp-up-directory-reuse-dir-buffer
     (kbd "l") 'diredp-find-file-reuse-dir-buffer)
  )
```

But this is not working for me. There is no error message when I launch emacs. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake. The Evil definitions with `evil-define-key` were being done before the `(evil-mode 1)` line.